std::variant multiple return types in a function
I am attempting to retrieve the value stored in a return variable with a type of variant, but I am struggling to make it work. Do you have any ideas? :)
I've tried almost everything, including templates and pointers, but with no success. The issue arises because the output variable type from the getValue function depends on the type of variant stored.
This is the current error :
Error   C2338   visit() requires the result of all potential invocations to have the same type and value category (N4835 [variant.visit]/2)
Question 2: how to make char types in variant work? (the commented out section)
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

// Note: platform dependent type sizes
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef signed char sint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef signed short sint16;
typedef unsigned long uint32;
typedef signed long sint32;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
typedef signed long long sint64;
typedef uint8 boolean;

typedef std::string SignalName;
typedef std::string SignalType;

// Define enum for signal types
enum class SignalTypeEnum {
    Double,
    UInt8,
    SInt8,
    UInt16,
    SInt16,
    UInt32,
    SInt32,
    UInt64,
    SInt64,
    Boolean,
    Int,
    Bool
};

// Define a map from string to SignalTypeEnum
SignalTypeEnum getSignalType(const SignalType& type) {
    if (type == "double") return SignalTypeEnum::Double;
    if (type == "uint8") return SignalTypeEnum::UInt8;
    if (type == "sint8") return SignalTypeEnum::SInt8;
    if (type == "uint16") return SignalTypeEnum::UInt16;
    if (type == "sint16") return SignalTypeEnum::SInt16;
    if (type == "uint32") return SignalTypeEnum::UInt32;
    if (type == "sint32") return SignalTypeEnum::SInt32;
    if (type == "uint64") return SignalTypeEnum::UInt64;
    if (type == "sint64") return SignalTypeEnum::SInt64;
    if (type == "boolean") return SignalTypeEnum::Boolean;
    if (type == "int") return SignalTypeEnum::Int;
    if (type == "bool") return SignalTypeEnum::Bool;
    // Default to Boolean if type is unrecognized
    return SignalTypeEnum::Double;
}

typedef std::variant<double, uint8, sint8, uint16, sint16, uint32, sint32, uint64, sint64, boolean, int, bool> SignalValue;

class ValueItem {
protected:
    SignalName  name;
    SignalType  type;
    SignalValue value;

    bool isValid() {
        // TODO: Implement validation logic
        return true;
    }

public:
    ValueItem(SignalName name = "", SignalType type = "", SignalValue value = 0)
        : name(name), type(type), value(value) {}

    SignalName getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    SignalType getType() const {
        return type;
    }

    SignalValue getValue() const {
        SignalTypeEnum signalType = getSignalType(type);
        //auto tmp_2 = std::get<bool>(value);
        switch (signalType) {
        case SignalTypeEnum::Double: 
            return std::get<0>(value);
        //case SignalTypeEnum::UInt8: return std::get<1>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::SInt8: 
            return std::get<2>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::UInt16: 
            return std::get<3>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::SInt16: 
            return std::get<4>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::UInt32: 
            return std::get<5>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::SInt32: 
            return std::get<6>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::UInt64: 
            return std::get<7>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::SInt64: 
            return std::get<8>(value);
        //case SignalTypeEnum::Boolean: return std::get<9>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::Int: 
            return std::get<10>(value);
        case SignalTypeEnum::Bool: 
            return std::get<11>(value);
        default: 
            return std::get<double>(value);
        }       
    }


    void setValue(SignalType type, SignalValue value) {
        this->type = type;
        this->value = value;
        if (!isValid()) {
            // TODO: Report the error
        }
    }

    void setName(SignalName name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
};

int main() {

    ValueItem item;
    item.setValue("bool", false);  // Now using SignalTypeEnum instead of string

    auto value_output = item.getValue();
    int index = value_output.index();

    auto result = std::visit([](auto v) -> decltype(v) { return v; }, value_output);
}


Why aren't you using the standard std::uint8_t etc instead of defining your own?

Aside: typedef uint8 boolean;??? bool exists, you are already using it, why do you need an integer type with this name?

Regarding the types, i had to due to memmory requirements on the device.

@Svatos Using the standard typedefs instead of creating your own doesn't affect the memory consumption on the device in any way. Why do you think typedef unsigned char uint8; and then using uint8 makes a smaller memory footprint that using the existing std::uint8_t?

There has to be a single type that you return from the visitor function passed to std::visit. If you want to do something that depends on the type of the value, that has to happen within the visitor.
N.b. your getValue is a very roundabout way of doing return value, but with exceptions if isValid is false. You don't need to carry a type alongside the variant, it does that for you.
class ValueItem {
private:
    SignalName  name;
    SignalValue value;

public:
    ValueItem(SignalName name = "", SignalValue value = 0)
        : name(name), value(value) {}

    SignalName getName() const {
        return name;
    }
 
    void setName(SignalName name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    SignalType getType() const {
        switch (value.index()) {
            case 0: return "double";
            case 1: return "uint8";
            case 2: return "sint8";
            case 3: return "uint16";
            case 4: return "sint16";
            case 5: return "uint32";
            case 6: return "sint32";
            case 7: return "uint64";
            case 8: return "sint64";
            case 9: return "boolean";
            case 10: return "int";
            case 11: return "bool";
            default: throw std::bad_variant_access();
        }
    }

    SignalValue getValue() const {
        return value;  
    }

    void setValue(SignalValue value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
};

int main() {
    ValueItem item("", false);
    auto value_output = item.getValue();
    std::visit([](auto result) -> void { std::cout << result; }, value_output );
    auto calculated = std::visit([](auto result) -> SignalValue { return result + 1; }, value_output );
}


Thank you for the answer but that is not what i am looking for (i am not sure if the sollution is possible)
This is the value_output:
{ index=11, value=false }
This is the calculated:
{ index=10, value=1 }
what i am searching for to have auto result that will have value from value_output.value so the result will be = false

@Svatos There needs to be a specific type. auto is not "every type", it is "determine the type from the initialiser". The result of std::visit needs to be a specific type. What do you want to do with that false value? Don't try to unwrap a variant, lift the operation you want to do to the unwrapped value into the visitor. I gave you two examples of that. I don't know what you want to do with result, ending main with auto result = false; is pointless.

let me try to explain, thank you, i acually need to unwrap the variant or to get to that value, i am using variant to transfer values from multiple modules for the correct data type.
the reason i need to unwrap them is to be able to use the value in another reading writing functions or for just the value checks and so one. So is the any acceptable option how to get the value from variant from my example? There i cant really use  std::get(value_output) because the std:get forbids me to. And i want to be able to store the result value in one variable according to its type. Svata

@Svatos no, you don't need to unwrap the variant yourself. Whatever you want to do can be done inside the visitor

Ok got you, does it mean that this opperation is not possible?

@Svatos what you are trying is yes. Like I said, the way that you access the value inside the variant is inside the visitor. The error message spells it out: "visit() requires the result of all potential invocations to have the same type and value category"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
